# Client-side URL Encoding of query parameters in a hyperlink

Tags: html, forms, http, get, urlencode

How can one encode query parameters of a URL which is displayed as a hyperlink.

Example of such a hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://site/page.html?param1=value1&param2=value2">MyPage</a>
```

I want so use only html capabilities to do this.

I can partially accomplish this with an html form using **http get** method but then I cant see the hyperlink and instead have to use a submit button(which I dont want to use):

```
<form method="get" action="http://site/page.html"> MyPage
 <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2"/>
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note that values of query parameters are rendered dynamically and can therfore contain special characters which must be encoded before sending them to the web server through http get method.

Can this be done using just HTML without need for introducing code at server-side encoding ?

Comment: Even with the form, you still need to HTML-encode them.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a button?

Comment: With form, I think the enctype attribute is set by default to application/x-www-form-urlencoded and this does the trick. I want to see hyperlinks and no buttons because I need multiple such hyperlinks on single page and buttons will not look nice

Comment: Would have been so simple if HTML had an input tag of type hyperlink or href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style a button to look like a hyperlink:

```
input.LinkButton {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    background: transparent;
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You'll probably also want `:hover` and `:active` styles.

Comment: Ok it works. But now I am having trouble with showing underline text-decoration on hover. I searched all over internet, and seems like many browsers dont support this attribute. I may run into browser compatibility issues now

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Javascript by calling `encodeURIComponent()`.

However, you should do it on the server, to support browsers with Javascript disabled.

Comment: I think the OP wants to build a query string from the form fields and append it to the action (ie build the get request) rather than uri encode the individual fields

Comment: I have no idea what the OP wants.  The question is very confusing.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I have simplified the question now

Comment: I still don't see why you can't use an `<a>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done using just HTML without need for introducing code at server-side encoding ?

No. Links take a URI. There would be no way to tell if `%` indicated the start of an encoded character or a literal `%`.

If you are building the links dynamically then you are already involving a programming language. Adding an encode routing to that is trivial in any language.